# Sqlite3 5.0.2 not working after build with electron

Tags: javascript, sqlite, electron, knex.js, electron-builder

I am trying to use sqlite3@5.0.2 in my electron app, It is working fine in development but When I build with electron-builder, It`s not working. How can I solved this problem?

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "knex": "^0.95.10",
  "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron .",    
  "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
  "desk-builder": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && electron-builder -w"
},
"devDependencies": {   
  "electron": "^11.4.8",
  "electron-builder": "^22.11.7",    
}
```